# How to keep dynamic content on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to `$stateParams`, `$transition$`, and `resolve` in `ui-router` in Angular and I am not sure which one to use to achieve my goal.

I have these 3 states (stated below), and the state `patents.list.item` is displayed when a user clicks an item in the template for `patents.list`. The `id` parameter is inserted into the URL, and what I want to happen, is when the user refreshers the page, it keeps the content related to the `id` displayed. At the moment it re-directs the user to `patent.list.item` with no item selected.

If I log the `$stateParams` in the controller, it shows the object that has been clicked. I need to know how to take that object and keep it populating the table that is displayed, after refresh. Any ideas?

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state("patents", {
       url: "/patents",
       templateUrl: "templates/patents/patent-nav.htm",
       controller: "patentListCtrl"
   })
  .state("patents.list", {
      url: "/list-patents",
      templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/list-patents.htm",
      controller: "patentListCtrl"
  })

  .state("patents.list.item", {
      url: "/:id",
      templateUrl: "templates/patents/list/patent-item.htm",
      params: {
          id: null,
          clientRef: null,
          renewalStatus: null,
          costBandEndDate: null,
          renewalCostNextStage: null,
          renewalDueDate: null,
       },
      controller: "patentItemCtrl"
  })
```

Comment: Remove id:null from your params. When you refresh the page all the params are getting reset to null. But since u need only the id to fetch the details of the item, you can fetch it from the URL

Comment: Ok, still not sure what I should be doing though. How do I get the content to reload if I refreshed the page?

Comment: If you eliminate the null it should automatically happen. If it's not, we'll probably need to see the controllers and the templates. Also, if you're using the new ui-router I'd highly recommend transitioning to components. Based on how you've structured your states, it looks like it should be a very easy refactor.

Comment: The content related to the id is displayed based on an API call? If so then you can fetch the id from the url using $stateParams and call API with it. But you have to remove id from params as it will reset it to null on refresh